# In Secret Misson Risk which player is the winner when 2 missions are simultaneously achieved?

Tags: risk

When playing the North American 1993 version of Secret Mission Risk, which player is the winner when 2 missions are simultaneously achieved?

Example: If your mission is, “Conquer Asia & Africa” and you have just one more territory to conquer to complete your mission, let’s say Madagascar which also has the last red troop on the map while another player has the mission “Destroy all Red Troops”, who wins when the last red troop dies and Madagascar is captured?

Does the other player holding the mission “Destroy all Red Troops” win as the red troop died before Madagascar was occupied? Does the player holding the mission “Conquer Asia & Africa” win as that player was the contributor to the final action accomplishing both missions? Would this game be considered a tie as both missions where accomplished simultaneously? Would the winner be the first to reveal their mission?

Comment: I've always assumed that it had to be your turn in order to have completed the mission.

Comment: In the 2003 version of Mission Risk, where you must accomplish 4 different missions on 4 different turns, it is indicated right on the mission card when you must reveal the mission, at start of turn, end of turn or just after gaing reenforcement of troops.  My question was related to the 1993 version of North American Risk.  Thoses missions can be acomplished at any time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [these rules](http://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/risk.pdf):

> The player who completes his or her mission first-and reveals the Mission
>   card to prove it-wins.

The rules make no mention of ordering, or of only being able to win at a specific time. If both players achieve a mission at *exactly* the same time, and both reveal their completed missions, then they have both fulfilled the win condition. You could assign a single winner in any arbitrary manner, but personally I'd say they both win; after all, does victory have to be exclusive?

**Extra note:** regarding the timing of defeating the final army and capturing a territory, the rules say:

> As soon as you defeat the last opposing army on a territory, you capture that territory and must occupy it immediately.

While the rules don't specifically set out timing, I'd say that the "*as soon as*" and "*immediately*" mean that capturing a territory happens at the same moment as defeating the last army.